# Scheduling multiple future notifications

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am currently debugging an issue with notifications inside my application. For some context, what I'd like to do is schedule notifications that should popup whenever a rocket launch is occurring. What I was doing was, after getting a list of scheduled launches from an API, I would take the launch date (in milliseconds since Jan 1 1970) and subtract the `System.currentTimeMillis()` from it. I would then use the resulting time to schedule the notification in the future, represented as `System.currentTimeMillis() + timeDifference`. I noticed that for whatever reason, only 1 notification is ever displayed.

I've tried debugging by scheduling notifications at 2, 4, and 6 minutes in the future, however a notification is only displayed at the 6 minute mark.

Some relevant code is below:

```
public void scheduleNotifications(List<Launch> launches) {

        for(int i = 0; i < launches.size(); i++) {

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = format.parse(launches.get(i).getWindowstart());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            long timeBetween = date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();

            Integer id = Long.valueOf(date.getTime()).intValue();

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, id);
            notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, getNotification(launches.get(i).getRocket().getName(), launches.get(i).getLocation().getPads().get(0).getName()));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            //Debug. Schedule at 2, 4, 6 minutes.
            if (i == 0) {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 120000, pendingIntent);
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 240000, pendingIntent);

            }
            if (i == 2) {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 360000, pendingIntent);

            }
        }
    }

private Notification getNotification(String rocketName, String padName) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setContentTitle("Upcoming Launch");
        builder.setContentText("A launch of a " + rocketName + " is about to occur at " + padName + ". Click for more info.");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.rocket_icon);
        return builder.build();
}
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification_id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    }

}
```

I'd like to know why only a single notification is ever presented, as well as what I need to add to achieve the previously stated goal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set an alarm using `AlarmManager`, it automatically cancels any existing alarm that has a matching `PendingIntent`. Since all your `PendingIntent`s contain the same components, every time you set an alarm, the previously set ones are automatically cancelled.

If you want to set multiple alarms, you must make sure that each of the `PendingIntent`s is unique. You can do this in one of the following ways:

- Use a different `requestCode` (second parameter to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`) for each `PendingIntent`
- Use a different ACTION in the `Intent` you pass to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` for each `PendingIntent`

Comment: Great, thank you. I've replaced the `requestCode` parameter with a unique integer (in this case just the value of `i`), and am now getting multiple notifications.